# Bootstrap Hide Nav-Tabs When There's No Content

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs

I simply want to hide a Nav-Tab if there's no content in the corresponding Div. I need to do this as the content is currently populated by a custom post type in Wordpress, so there will not all ways be content to show.

```
    <div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

If for example div #profile had no content, I'd like the nav-tab li for Profile to be hidden.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you having trouble with a specific aspect of hiding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:empty` selector to find the empty `tabpanel` elements. You would then need to loop over those to hide the related tab. Try this:

```js
$('.tab-pane:empty').each(function() {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + this.id + '"]').closest('li').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="tabpanel">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile"></div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">Messages</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```